# No WM_QUIT after PostQuitMessage in WM_SIZE handler

Tags: windows, winapi

I have the following code snippet:

Window procedure:

```
LRESULT window_procedure(HWND window, UINT message_type, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message_type)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProcA(window, message_type, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Event loop:

```
while (true)
{
    MSG message;
    while (PeekMessageA(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (message.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            return message.wParam;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessageA(&message);
    }
}
```

I expect every time as soon as I resize, the event loop terminates since it will receives the `WM_QUIT` message. However, I don't seem to get this behaviour. The event loop only quits after I release the resizing grab. And more weirdly, that only happens occationally. Sometimes the quit message just seems to got no where!

Comment: Seems you also want to quit when you get the WM_SIZING message.  Or WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE.  Hard to tell, this is too odd.  Do get familiar with a debugging tool like Spy++ or WinSpy.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you know if there's a good way to exit resizing modal loop early? Also how would the tools you suggested help with debugging?

Comment: Window resizing runs its own modal message loop, while you have the mouse button down, and so your own message loop isn't picking up the `WM_QUIT` until the sizing stops. You can send your window a `WM_CANCELMODE` message to cancel the sizing loop.

Answer (score 0):

**And more weirdly, that only happens occationally. Sometimes the quit message just seems to got no where!**

You can print all the messages received by `PeekMessageA` and the messages received by `window_procedure` for comparison, and you will find the reason.

```
while (true)
{
    MSG message;
    while (PeekMessageA(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        printf("Message: %x\n", message.message);
        if (message.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            return message.wParam;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessageA(&message);
    }
}
```

and

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    printf("WndProc : %x\n", message);
    ...
```

After testing, when dragging the border, `PeekMessageA` will only receive `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` messages.

As @Jonathan Potter said that, window resizing runs its own modal message loop. This is why you cannot receive `WM_QUIT`, which is processed in its own modal message loop.

If you call `PostQuitMessage(0)` in `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`, you will find that `PeekMessageA` can receive `WM_QUIT`.

Comment: @Rui Liu Hi, is the answer useful to you? If you have any question, please feel free to tell me.